# JQuery $.post ,form...Send Additional data using post on each click of submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, post

I created a form

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="send_data()"/>
</form>
```

and I need to send some additional data to the test.php beside
"name", to implement this I used JQuery's $.post method :

```
function send_data(){
var foo = $("#foo").text();
$.post( "test.php", { foo: foo} );
{alert(foo)};
}
```

But it doesn't work, I put alert function to see whether it calls it on every click,
and it does call send_data function..
So probably I misunderstood the way $.post works....

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Your JQuery syntax is not correct. Take a look at some examples

Comment: The alert should work just fine, is it not working? Of course the form still submits and the page reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the normal submit action by returning `false` from the `onsubmit`:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="send_data(); return false;"/>
```

To include the input value in your AJAX call, you need to get it explicitly:

```
function send_data(){
    var foo = $("#foo").text();
    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    $.post( "test.php", { foo: foo, name: name} );
}
```

Comment: I suppose in this case data that was gotten from input won't be send to the .php file

Comment: That's true. When you use AJAX, only what you put in the AJAX call gets sent.